# Multiple HTML Fields for SELECT Query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Is it possible to post form data into a SELECT query so that the query can find results based on what is entered?

For example, I have three fields:
Marketing Agreement Number: ***_*__*_*__**
Company ID: ***_*__*_*__*_*_**
Start Date: ***_*__*_*__*_*_**

Say I don't know what the Marketing Agreement Number is, and I would like to find by Company ID instead of Marketing Agreement Number. Or if I just wanted to find what promo started on a particular date (or range of dates) I would just enter a start date and not input anything in the other two.

Currently my query is this:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Items, Promotions, Vendor_Prices, Vendors, Sales_Accounts
WHERE Items.itemid = Promotions.itemid AND
Vendors.vendorid = Promotions.vendorid AND
Vendor_Prices.vendorid = Vendors.vendorid AND
Vendor_Prices.itemid = Items.itemid AND
promoid = '$man'");
```

Where $man is the post information for Marketing Agreement Number. Sorry if this is a little confusing, I can clarify if necessary.

EDIT: 
I figured it out. I just changed my query in the WHERE field to have OR and LIKE rather than just "=".

```
promoid LIKE '$man' OR Vendors.vendorid LIKE '$cid' OR startdate = '$pstart'
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question.  If you want to run a query based on what information a person enters into a form and what they do not you could use some if logic.

```
if ($_POST["man"] != "") {
    $query += sprintf(" AND promoId = '$man'", $_POST["man"]);
}
if ($_POST["companyId"] != "") {
    $query += sprintf(" AND companyId = '$companyId'", $_POST["companyId"]);
}
if ($_POST["startDate"] != "") {
    $query += sprintf(" AND startDate= '$startDate'", $_POST["startDate"]);
}
```